# Caffe: predict multiple labels at once (in Python)

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, hdf5, caffe

In caffe, I would like to be able to predict multiple labels at once, such as keyboard arrow keys: two keys could be pressed at the same time. I am trying to drive a virtual F1 car in the `TM Nation Forever` game with a convolutional neural network, I plan to gather and shape the training data very soon and I would like to know if I do things right.

I think this post would give a good example on how to do such classification in Python, I did not found any satisfying examples on how to do that yet.

Could someone please validate that this way to gather and represent the data in the neural network will work as I expect to:

### HDF5 python code

```
comp_kwargs = {'compression': 'gzip', 'compression_opts': 1}

with h5py.File(train_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.create_dataset('data_img', data=X, **comp_kwargs)
    f.create_dataset('data_speed', data=S.astype(np.float_), **comp_kwargs)

    f.create_dataset('label_forward', data=f.astype(np.int_), **comp_kwargs)
    f.create_dataset('label_backward', data=b.astype(np.int_), **comp_kwargs)
    f.create_dataset('label_left', data=l.astype(np.int_), **comp_kwargs)
    f.create_dataset('label_right', data=r.astype(np.int_), **comp_kwargs)

with open(train_filename_list_txt, 'w') as f:
    f.write(train_filename + '\n')
```

### Info about HDF5 data shapes

Input:

```
data_img: 
-> number N x channel K x height H x width W

data_speed:
-> number N  x  1 float number (from 0.0 to 1.0)
```

Output:

*Note: I use numpy's "int_" to get a label class to be classified.*

```
label_forward:
-> number N  x  1 integer number (0 or 1)

label_backward:
-> number N  x  1 integer number (0 or 1)

label_left:
-> number N  x  1 integer number (0 or 1)

label_right:
-> number N  x  1 integer number (0 or 1)
```

### Convolutional neural network architecture

I have put some semi-related comments here, I would appreciate any opinion on the architecture of the network too if it can make it more performant :)

```
import numpy as np

import caffe
from caffe import layers as L
from caffe import params as P

def cnn(hdf5, batch_size):
    n = caffe.NetSpec()
    n.data_img, n.data_speed, n.label_forward, n.label_backward, n.label_left, label_right = (
        L.HDF5Data(batch_size=batch_size, source=hdf5, ntop=6)
    )

    n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=7, num_output=32, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool1 = L.Pooling(n.conv1, kernel_size=3, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
    n.drop1 = L.Dropout(n.pool1, in_place=True)
    n.relu1 = L.ReLU(n.drop1, in_place=True)

    n.conv2 = L.Convolution(n.relu1, kernel_size=5, num_output=42, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool2 = L.Pooling(n.conv2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
    n.drop2 = L.Dropout(n.pool2, in_place=True)
    n.relu2 = L.ReLU(n.drop2, in_place=True)

    n.conv3 = L.Convolution(n.relu2, kernel_size=5, num_output=50, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool3 = L.Pooling(n.conv3, kernel_size=3, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
    n.drop3 = L.Dropout(n.pool3, in_place=True)
    n.relu3 = L.ReLU(n.drop3, in_place=True)

    n.conv4 = L.Convolution(n.relu3, kernel_size=3, num_output=64, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool4 = L.Pooling(n.conv4, kernel_size=3, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.AVE)
    # Data of shape `batch_size*64*3*3` out of this layer (if dropout ignored), 
    # for a total of `batch_size*576` neurons.
    # Would you recommend to downsize this `3*3` feature map to `2*2`
    # or even `1*1` and to remove dropout at this level?
    n.drop4 = L.Dropout(n.pool4, in_place=True)
    n.relu4 = L.ReLU(n.drop4, in_place=True)

    n.join_speed = L.Concat(n.relu4, n.data_speed, in_place=True)
    # Note that I might be wrong on how the parameters are passed to the concat layer 
    n.ip1 = L.InnerProduct(n.join_speed, num_output=512, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.sig1 = L.Sigmoid(n.ip1, in_place=True)

    n.ip_f = L.InnerProduct(n.sig1, num_output=2, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.accuracy_f = L.Accuracy(n.ip_f, n.label_forward)
    n.loss_f = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip_f, n.label_forward)

    n.ip_b = L.InnerProduct(n.sig1, num_output=2, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.accuracy_b = L.Accuracy(n.ip_b, n.label_backward)
    n.loss_b = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip_b, n.label_backward)

    n.ip_l = L.InnerProduct(n.sig1, num_output=2, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.accuracy_l = L.Accuracy(n.ip_l, n.label_left)
    n.loss_l = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip_l, n.label_left)

    n.ip_r = L.InnerProduct(n.sig1, num_output=2, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.accuracy_r = L.Accuracy(n.ip_r, n.label_right)
    n.loss_r = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip_r, n.label_right)

    return n.to_proto()

with open('cnn_train.prototxt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(
        cnn(train_filename_list_txt, 100)
    ))
```

Moreover, I would like to have only one of the left arrow key or right arrow key pressed at once. Instead of doing it programactically afterwards, would it be a good idea to fusion label_right and label_left like this considering I will use some `SoftmaxWithLossLayer`:

```
label_right:
-> number N  x  1 integer number (0 for left or 1 for right)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what I did was the right thing to do for the task, except that the concat layer might not work because of the difference in the joined layers' shape.
I tested this with the cifar-100 dataset where there are both coarse and fine labels, and it worked well.